# Why are the address two different values the same when printed as function parameters?

Tags: rust

```
fn main() {
    println!("{:p}", &"aravindh");
    println!("{:p}", &"test");
    address_of(&"aravindh");
    address_of(&"test");
}

fn address_of<A>(a:&A){
    println!("{:p}", &a);
}
```

The output is:

```
0x10da08260
0x10da08278
0x7fff52231990
0x7fff52231990
```

While the address of first two strings are different, why are they same when printed via the `address_of` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're printing the address of the parameter `a`, not the address of the thing it points to.

```
fn address_of<A>(a: &A){
    println!("{:p}", a);
}
```

Comment: @AravindhS: It's right there.  \**points at code example in answer*\*

Comment: Oops. I missed it. Thank you.